# TypeScript - The property does not exist in the type, but it actually exists

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make my own xml builder on typescript. I have this issue:

```
Property 'children' does not exist on type 'XMLNode'.
  Property 'children' does not exist on type 'XMLNodeWithoutClidren'.
```

its my code:

```
export interface Stringable {
  toString(): string
}

export type XMLProperty<T extends Stringable> = T

export interface XMLNodeWithoutClidren {
  readonly attributes: Map<string, XMLProperty<Stringable>>;
}

export interface XMLNodeWithClidren extends XMLNodeWithoutClidren {
  readonly children: Set<XMLNode>;
}

export type XMLNode = XMLNodeWithoutClidren | XMLNodeWithClidren;

class NodeWithoutChildrenBuilder {
  static build(node: XMLNodeWithoutClidren): string {
    return `some logic`
  }
}

class NodeWithChildrenBuilder {
  static build(node: XMLNodeWithClidren): string {
    return `some logic`
  }
}

class NodeParser {
  static parse(node: XMLNode) {
    if (node.children) {
      return NodeWithChildrenBuilder.build(node);
    }

    return NodeWithoutChildrenBuilder.build(node);
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZRimQHNMAjAGzwG8AoOOGCQ4pEgCgEoAuOAZyKk6AXzp1QkWEwCeYPAA0AsgBkAClAjzYMgDwAVOKFRIAJvwJD2FagD44AXjj7xk6PGSoMORaoByEKbAAOoIMAAWEACuMADClAimUMBIcPSMyZimEEiUMnCYMELkMcD8fEqYYLqCbCQANHDK6praMHqspDbAtrYA3KKu4O6IKGhYuE3%20gSFh4fGJyanGKeZTKgFBoRHRcQlJKWkMcJnZufnY4QiUB0h8%20MAwus2bPQNiEsPS7fLrr45-GbbSIxBa3OAAH0BWzmYKWAzo2EomH4FlewN2sSuNyWACEotcglAjoxBIUENg4CVCRwkDM%20C8gXNMfslrwBFYSCTGCdHlEoKkAAb8CAAWzwlAgJApguOYg%20SJRaKZESxhLxBJuaG5ZJgFKpmtMtPp0NmqtZKXZtVI3IyfIFcGFYolUplcsGiORqLgrzUmCg-G16Q55MpYH9geNQQZ0yCXFtiHQcCjwAAdJd1ZaE3aYPzUujYdjbvjCWhU9SbimuAMeXAPrXkrmHQWdqCixrS1By4aqzW66IgA)

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: you might want to fix the `Clidren` typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a common case for a custom type guard:

```
function nodeHasChildren(node: XMLNode) : node is XMLNodeWithClidren {
    return (node as XMLNodeWithClidren).children !== undefined;
}
```

and then you can rewrite your

```
if (node.children) {
```

to

```
if (nodeHasChildren(node)) {
```

which should correctly narrow the type in the scope.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZRimQHNMAjAGzwG8BYAKDjhgkOKRIAoBKALjgBnIqUYBfRo1CRYLAJ5g8ADQCyAGQAKUCIthyAPABU4oVEgAmggiM4VqAPjgBeOIckNp0eMlQYcy9QA5CHNgAHUEGAALCABXGABhSgRzKGAkOHomODTMcwgkSjk4TBgRcnjgQQEVTDB9YQ4SABo4VU1tXRgDdlI7YHt7AG5xd09ZHzQsXDagkPDIqKSUtIzTdMtZtWDQiOi4xOTU9MzGZlz8wuLsKIRKY6QBfGAYfXadgZGGCQYpcC95Ioth9nMD5nsYvFlg84AAfMG7RbQ1ZfRjYSiYQRWD4Qg4JW73VYAIVid1CUFO2WEpQQ2DgFTJXCQ8wE73BizxR1W-CENhIlOY5xesSgGQABoIIABbPCUCAkWlis5wH4-NEYrFwHFIgkPElktAC3k0ukM+5MlkIhbRZHpHmNUhGoUwEXiyUyuByhXYJXZVXudCxJDYGAIApwZmhAASmPxZNWFtCrLmoR4cAEkbwCCsbMRNq5JyygpywtFcETeExVohtqQPAAdDd4ycAIROFxB0LoZDAcxfNUMdGY7HzDSYKCCQ1F42hulgceTivJ7bzNPT5gIdDlzMxwRxwnpCs8NfK4tpF1l7U23XE0n3ND1s3mI9fYsDs+ljJXyGJG-pfX3lAj53s+mY8K+KriEAA)

Comment: Do note that [the TS team recommends](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/15256#discussion_r154843152) using [`in` operator narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) instead of [custom type guard functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) in cases like this.

Comment: @jcalz: thanks, that's almost the same code with an exception that "in" is inlined, thus can possibly be faster.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to access a property which isn't known to exist on an object, the compiler will warn you about it:

```
interface Foo {
  x: string;
}
function f(foo: Foo) {
  foo.y // <-- error, property 'y' does not exist on type 'Foo'
}
```

This doesn't mean that the property *cannot* exist, it's just that the compiler has no idea if the property exists or not, and so it considers the access a probable error.  And because it has no idea if the property exists or not, it treats it as having [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any), because it could be anything (not necessarily `undefined`):

```
const b = { x: "", y: 1 };
f(b); // okay
```

---

In your case, you are trying to access the `children` property on an object which is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of two types: `XMLNodeWithChildren` which is known to have a `children` property of a certain type, and `XMLNodeWithoutChildren` which is not.

Despite the name, the compiler cannot know that `XMLNodeWithoutChildren` *lacks* a `children` property. Indeed, your own code defines `XMLNodeWithChildren` as an [extension](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#extending-types) of `XMLNodeWithoutChildren`. By [the rules of subtyping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#starting-out), every `XMLNodeWithChildren` is also a perfectly valid `XMLNodeWithoutChildren`. And there are all kinds of potential perfectly valid `XMLNodeWithoutChildren` extensions:

```
interface XMLNodeWithNumericChildren extends XMLNodeWithoutChildren {
  children: number;
}
```

So, *technically*, faced with an object of type `XMLNodeWithChildren | XMLNodeWithoutChildren`, the compiler has no idea what, if anything, can be concluded about the `children` property.  It would be unsafe for the compiler to think that the type of the property is `Set<XMLNode> | undefined`.  It has to consider it `any`, and that doesn't help with control flow narrowing.

Case in point, let's imagine that `NodeWithChildrenBuilder.build()` actually does something `Set`-like with its argument's `children` property:

```
class NodeWithChildrenBuilder {
  static build(node: XMLNodeWithChildren): string {
    node.children.has(node); // compiles fine
    return `some logic`
  }
}
```

You can then  cause a runtime error if you call `NodeParser.parse()` with an argument with some random `children` property, and the compiler is not guaranteed to catch this:

```
const x = { attributes: new Map(), children: 123 }
NodeParser.parse(x) // no compiler error, but RUNTIME ERROR!
```

That's what's "wrong" with your code.

---

Of course, in practice, it seems unlikely that someone will hand you a pathological `node` of a type like `XMLNodeWithNumericChildren`.  And so while it's technically unsafe to use the presence of `children` to narrow an `XMLNode` to an `XMLNodeWithChildren`, you'd like to do it anyway.

If so, the easiest way for you to deal with this is to use [the `in` operator type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) like this:

```
class NodeParser {
  static parse(node: XMLNode) {
    if ("children" in node) {  // <-- in operator here
      return NodeWithChildrenBuilder.build(node); // okay
    }
    return NodeWithoutChildrenBuilder.build(node); // okay
  }
}
```

This works with no compiler errors now.  Note that this is *still technically unsafe*.  Someone can still call `NodeParser.parse(x)` like above and get a runtime error. But this lack of safety is considered acceptable in order to give people a way to do the kind of check you're doing: see [this comment on microsoft/TypeScript#15256](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/15256#discussion_r154843152), the PR that implemented `in` guarding:

> We considered the soundness aspect and it's not very different from existing soundness issues around aliased objects with undeclared properties. [...] The reality is that most unions are already correctly disjointed and don't alias enough to manifest the problem. Someone writing an `in` test is not going to write a "better" check; all that really happens in practice is that people add type assertions or move the code to an equally-unsound user-defined type predicate. On net I don't think this is any worse than the status quo (and is better because it induces fewer user-defined type predicates, which are error-prone if written using `in` due to a lack of typo-checking).

So, one solution is for you to change `if (node.children)` to `if ("children" in node)`, forget about pathological `XMLNode` values, and move on with your life!

---

If upon reading the above though, you still worry about pathological cases, you can refactor your types so that `XMLNodeWithoutChildren` actually *cannot have* a defined `children` property value.  It could look like this:

```
interface BaseXMLNode {
  readonly attributes: Map<string, XMLProperty<Stringable>>;
}

export interface XMLNodeWithoutChildren extends BaseXMLNode {
  children?: never;
}

export interface XMLNodeWithChildren extends BaseXMLNode {
  readonly children: Set<XMLNode>;
}

export type XMLNode = XMLNodeWithoutChildren | XMLNodeWithChildren;
```

Now we have a `BaseXMLNode` that both `XMLNodeWithoutChildren` and `XMLNodeWithChildren` derive from.  The `XMLNodeWithoutChildren` type has an [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) `children` property of [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  Since there are no values of type `never`, an optional property of type `never` is essentially the same as a prohibited property. The only value you'll ever see at the `children` property is `undefined`.

And that means `XMLNode` is now a truly [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) where the `children` property can be used to tell which type of `XMLNode` you have:

Once we do that, your original `NodeParser` code works again:

```
class NodeParser {
  static parse(node: XMLNode) {
    if (node.children) {
      return NodeWithChildrenBuilder.build(node); // okay
    }

    return NodeWithoutChildrenBuilder.build(node); // okay
  }
}
```

and now those pathological cases are impossible, since `children` needs to either be a `Set<...>` or `undefined`:

```
const x = { attributes: new Map(), children: 123 }
NodeParser.parse(x) // error!
// ------------> ~
// Types of property 'children' are incompatible.
```

This solution is as type-safe as you can get; it might or might not be worth the refactoring to get such type safety, depending on your use cases.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkgJbAAuEATgGYLIBiA9o3oUUgB4BcSUZlpAOYBuNgF821AK7B4ZYo2BJqACmrMeTRgEpW7ZcwB0ATyQB6M0gA8AWhtIqlRpQA0SGE5hUypgOTHfJAATRmgkYEYyBw5iPiRFJB8vJF8tX3F8TKJ4RTiAIyQAXjxOHgAiMrdjHgBGJDFRIlU87WFzS0YAaxBjTLZQSFg6JABlYjAYDAh6Yg5WNiIIDhhnKNIKGmGR-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-qWiGgUQxDUEgKhlFBIbAGUWLhDGug0VyKGruupF-hWAHAA+LJUIYH5BMxSESQ8yHcqh0lNq6LbyYppKUCpnafuBGlHPhuqETkwBxHMxS4EgQoimKUA8MAEAAO5IJKMCXG4-EFrUABMADMp7sGRjHKXAlEQCoHC6BY3IyPIu6OM4GSPAM0BwHiABKEC4mQzjzImGLJkamx4mqcIaqB5UNRcQELvc57oi8bypp8vyKsqPignakLQq18KasiqL3LVuLIG29YQFmoF+ooAZuQIooUJ5-lSjKC7ygNgIqlYE0alqcZaVVPVYhs80lvpObTtBtpLBCDqLVRK3iRe8kAPxeRAABuVBXV10S3XNJq-uat7yaNn1LT9J5rfypghV6YYRlGsOxp1hFJr1aZ45meNTnmr1Fo9sl3sA1b6JeJFPW6lMCcZ1EnnR77mWp4E8F9y14+1twcTpUnoTuyBYUeJ42fGdnEdecP-lTHNPr9L5kP2PMjvzNMq3JVMi0IYvgZB8mwfBllXfoK5oUgW5S3uB6y3hBM1krMmkuRiUa1z2tvgxiXMaxzpidpXE8ebmOAWLkkOyzdPq2ZeuibbtnafbemyYZau88pqnqRn8vXReuRRE5JSbcQ23iuEvl7YF2jBfJ4VRaXsV+4YCVMSl7QOJQTiUAAhPcaV2JPU+T0iAB+4+WCCfXQow3EeEqQIpLHwCBBRyCkDkEz9hqhi5ZkYhAA)

Comment: Thanks for u long answer